# meteorjs and mongodb : delta for part of huge document updated

Tags: meteor

With metorjs and mongodb , in a collection if i have a huge document and only a part of that is updated. Will the entire document will be sent to the clients or just the diff?

Let say for example in a mongodb collection say person if i have a document "

```
{
   personName:"abc",
   businessContacts:[
      {
          "contactName":"pqr",
          "phone":12121        // if this gets updated in mongodb .. what will be sent via meteor
      },

     //1000 such more ... 
   ]
}
```

and user is sent out the entire document in query | find() .. // the entire document

Answer (score 0):

Initially the entire document will be sent. When you make an update to the database only a diff containing that change would be sent

Comment: awesome ! which means if the document is of size 10kb , later(non first) updates of few bytes of data will only result in few bytes of wire transfer. awesome, and it can be at any level within the document right ? Is there any recommended database schema for mongodb with meteor>

Comment: Yes it's nothing too complicated. So long as what you're changing is just a field and not some part of a field. I.e If you have a `{'fieldname':'value'}` and `value` is some 4000 byte value, and you change 3 byes of it its still going to send the new value and not just the small change in that value. If you change it in the way you're saying only the updated fields are sent down.

Comment: As I mentioned before it would send down the diffs. For your specific setup have a look at the network tab in your chrome developer console to see the exact diff sent down to clear any confusion you might have. But yes only the field is sent down that has changed, but not part of a field that can't be represented with a key like some small part of a big string.

Comment: in nested part of document.. entire part is sent over the wire

Comment: @naveen in a nested document the top level field that has changed containing the changes is sent down. Not the entire document.

Comment: agreed, but if it is too nested at 2 levels.. changes till level 1 is sent down ..

Comment: To see exactly what is being sent, use the [Realtime DDP Analyzer](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer)